# Change grid layout at breaking points with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I want to create a grid view for 12 images in react bootstrap.
In md and above, the images should be arranged 6x2 (6 on top, 6 on bottom)
For sm and above, it should be 2x6
for xs it should be 1x12

but there does not appear to be such a grid feature within bootstrap
and react bootstrap does not provide a useBreakpoint or similar tool to get the current screen size.

So is there an elegant way to make this happen? Dynamically change the grid layout based on boostrap breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's [grid view](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) `row` and `col` are implemented using flex-box and it **does** support [bootstrap's breakpoint system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints) which are supported by react-bootstrap as well. (Unless you are talking about `display: grid` which all related css properties are not supported by Bootstrap)

For example, `col-sm-6` applies `col-6` to sizes `sm` **or above**. Consider a div with `col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2` breakpoints: For sizes that `size >= md` it will be applied `col-2`, for sizes that `sm <= size < md` it will be applied `col-6`, and for sizes that `size < sm` it will be applied `col-12`.

In [react-bootstrap responsive grids](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/layout/grid/#responsive-grids) they are written in this way:

```js
<Row>
    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={2}>
        1
    </Col>
    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={2}>
        2
    </Col>
    ...
</Row>
```

Which is same as native Bootstrap:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    10
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    12
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The pure html version works, the react one doesn't. I think there it only affects sizing

Comment: Did you [import the stylesheet for bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets) in the react index page? It applies the exact same css as the native one. You can check the inspection tool to see if it actually applies the bootstrap classes

Comment: yep, my mistake, sorry

Comment: No problem! Was glad to help